# PostGIS Voronoi Polygons with extend_to parameter

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, voronoi-thiessen

I am creating voronoi polygons for locations inside a country, using PostGIS.
The function creates these areas for ~80,000 locations in less than a second.

However, I can only get the polygons to extend to the default envelope area, which is 50% of the bounding box of points.

```
WITH voronoi (vor) AS 
 (SELECT ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom))) FROM public.branches_atms_0601)
SELECT (vor).path, (vor).geom FROM voronoi;
```

This generates the polygon(s) below:

[image]

What I would like it to do is to clip this to the footprint of UK. This can apparently be defined within the function https://postgis.net/docs/ST_VoronoiPolygons.html
However when I try to run it with my UK footprint polygon, I get the error with the code...

```
WITH voronoi (vor) AS 
 (SELECT ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom), public."Dissolved")) FROM 
public.branches_atms_0601)
SELECT (vor).path, (vor).geom FROM voronoi;

ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "public"
LINE 2: ...LECT ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geom), public."Di...
                                                         ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 82
```

How can I fix this? I assume the issue is coming from assigning the *extends_to* parameter incorrectly, but I don't know how to approach it...

Answer (score 8):

Generally, in SQL you specify the *(schema qualified) relation (table) identifier* (i.e. `public.branches_atms_0601` as part of the `FROM` expression, and optionally add an `ALIAS` (e.g. `AS br_at`), after which you can use that identifier (or `ALIAS` exclusively, when added) throughout the query.

However, it is **required** that **all relations used in the query** are *somehow* referenced **in a `FROM` clause**, either directly (on multiple occasions) or via a `JOIN` expression!

When stating `public."Dissolved"` PostgreSQL looks for an **already referenced relation** (where it also expects a column only)!

---

Assuming that you actually want to refer to and use a column `geom` in relation `public."Dissolved"`, and given that `public."Dissolved"` only has **a single row**, you could e.g. *sub-select* the wanted `public."Dissolved".geom` value in the function directly:

```
SELECT ST_Dump(
         ST_VoronoiPolygons(
           ST_Collect(br.geom),
           0.0,
           (SELECT geom FROM public."Dissolved" [WHERE <it_returns_only_a_single_row>])
         )
       )
FROM   public.branches_atms_0601 AS br
;
```

It is likely that the UK footprint consists of multiple geometries (or a *Multi* geometry); make it so that the sub-query returns a single (*Multi*) geometry then.

Note that you will have to either

- add the `tolerance` parameter to the function call
- use the named notation `extend_to => (<sub-select>)` in the function call

to fulfill the function signature.

---

**However:**

The function will use the **envelope** of the `extend_to` geometry, i.e. the bounding box, and only if it is **larger than the default geometry**!

If the exact outlines of the UK are desired, **you'd need to get the intersection between the function output and the footprint explicitly**:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(dmp.geom, ds.geom) AS geom
FROM   (
    SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
    FROM   public.branches_atms_0601
) t,   LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(t.geom)) AS dmp
JOIN   public."Dissolved" AS ds
  ON   ST_Intersects(dmp.geom, ds.geom)
;
```